# Where to get Traffic images dataset from

Tags: image, deep-learning, dataset

I am working in deeplearning field. I would like to work with the traffic analysis/ traffic contorl system.

- Where do I find the dataset relating to the road traffic in the form of images.
- Can anyone help me with websites to find the traffic images dataset.
- Are there any publicly available road traffic image datasets?
- If not, whom should I contact for road traffic images for working in purely Academic front.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to google out to the maximum extent possible. I found traffic signals image dataset which was luckily publicly available. I found it [here](https://www.kaggle.com/mbornoe/lisa-traffic-light-dataset)

LISA Traffic Light Dataset is traffic light signals dataset with more than 44 minutes of annotated traffic light data.

Quite a large data set of 4GB.

I would be happy if more sources can be provided for enabling research in Intelligent Transportation system.